# Как проигрывать музыку после скрытия блока?

Tags: скрипт, javascript, css

Такой вопрос, поставила себе на сайт скрипт [РадиоПоток](http://radiopotok.ru/radio_on_site).

Теперь такая запара: необходимо скрыть блок, но чтобы музыка продолжала играть. Но вот не задача, как только блок становится 
`Dislay:none`, 
то тут же перестает проигрываться.

Пробовала  `$("#radio").slideToggle();` Тоже не помогает. Как быть? Желательно красиво...

Comment: а visibility:hidden тоже не помогает?

Comment: а можно как нибудь изменить свойство top(css) плавно, чтобы на одной кнопке было появление и исчезновение?

Comment: Если бы был предоставлен код или ссылка на сайт где он находится - помочь было бы легче :)

Comment: Эмм...если бы Вы были внимательней, то Вам было бы легче...Так как в самой первой строке указанна ссылка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен за результат, но думаю можно попробовать так

```
<style>
#radio{ 
   overflow-y: hidden;
   height: 50px; /* Или какая там высота блока? */
}
</style>
<script>
    // скрытие блока
    function showOrHideRadio() {
        if($("#radio").css("height") == "0px") {
            $("#radio").animate({"height":"50px"});//Или какая там высота?
        } else {
            $("#radio").animate({"height":"0px"});
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="showOrHideRadio()" value="Скрыть/Показать">
```

Comment: Спасибо (+ вам за это) за старание помочь
Но мне больше помогло, если такое при нажатии в одну кнопку, сменялось
то есть:
имеется одна кнопка, на открытие и сокрытие. toggle или как там...не получается

Comment: Ну это же просто. Подредактировал свой пример, теперь он и скрывает и показывает )

Comment: Спасибо)))) Я точно так же реализовала сама) И тут захожу Вы так же)

Answer (score 2):

`style.position.top` позволяет получить доступ к свойству `top`.

`setinterval` позволяет обеспечить плавность.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если не позволяет проигрывать при `display:none`, то можно попробовать некрасиво сделать. Убирай элемент из потока документа - делай ему `position: absolute`, и потом выноси его за пределы рабочей области - `left: -5000`.

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости `slideToggle()` присаивает `display:block|none`.

А если скрываемому блоку будет присваиваться `visiblity:visible|hidden` то вероятность что музыка продолжит проигрываться.

З.Ы. К сожелению не могу протестировать данный пример и дать конкретный ответ!

Comment: Так и есть, но мне необходимо произвести visiblity:visible|hidden красиво...примерно так же, как и slideToggle()

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя просто сделать его прозрачным

```
$("#radio").css("opacity", "0")
```

Comment: Нет нельзя, так как он перекрывает другие блоки, а есть opacity юзать, то разницы ни какой, доступ к блокам, которые под ним, всё равно отсутствует.